# WFFM Connection String name

Tags: wffm

I'm trying to save some information into SQL through WFFm's Save action & couldnt get it right :(
i have configured wffm connection string as
[image]

May i know what is the default connectiostring name for WFFM ? is it 'wffm' or 'wfm'
Some analysis from my end:

**Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config**

[image]

**Sitecore.Forms.config**

[image]

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and WFFM do you use?

Comment: Sitecore 8.1 Update-1 & WFFM 8.1 Update-1

Comment: ```Xdb.Enbaled=true``` on your Sitecore instance or you use CMS-Only mode?

Comment: Its 'off' since i do not have XDB setup in my instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding to the following blogpost (https://citizensitecore.com/2016/05/11/wffm-and-cms-only-mode-in-sitecore-8-1/) by default Sitecore saves the WFFM form values in MongoDB after Sitecore 8.0 version.

The default connectionStringName is `wfm`. To make this work on CMS-Only instance you need to overwrite the `connectionStringName` in the `sqlFormsDataProvider` in Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config file.

**Solution step by step**

> 1. First, you need to take the empty `Sitecore_Wffm` SQL database that was placed in the %webroot%/Data folder and attach it to your SQL
>      Server.
> 2. Next, you must add a new connection string in `App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config` for this database. `<add
>      name="wfm" connectionString="insert connection string here" />` Yes,
>      the name of this connection string should be wfm.  In
>      Sitecore.Forms.config, there is a `WFM.ConnectionString` setting that
>      specifies the name of the connection string to use.  It is wfm out of
>      the box.
>      **For the record, while this step isn’t in the installation guide for 8.1-compliant versions of WFFM, I have seen it in official documentation somewhere, I just can’t seem to recall where.  And if
>      it’s that difficult to find, it’s a problem.
> 3. Finally, in Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config, in the /sitecore/wffm/analytics node, there is an element called
>      `<formsDataProvider>`.
>
> Update this connection string name to match what is in
>   `Sitecore.Forms.config` and you should be golden!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just patch `WFM.ConnectionString` from Sitecore.Forms.config instead (setting this to wffm)?